# Key exchange for trusted publishing on pypi?

Tags: github-actions, openid-connect, pypi

recently trusted publishing has hit pypi.

It's some sort of key exchange without an explicit secret from Github.
I struggle to get api_token back from pypi.

```
        # retrieve the ambient OIDC token
        resp=$(curl -H "Authorization: bearer $ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" \
                       "$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL&audience=pypi")
        echo "RESP ${resp}"
        oidc_token=$(jq '.value' <<< "${resp}")
        echo "OIDC ${oidc_token}"
        
        # exchange the OIDC token for an API token
        resp=$(curl -X POST https://pypi.org/_/oidc/github/mint-token -d '{"token":"${oidc_token}"}')
        echo "RESP ${resp}"
        api_token=$(jq '.token' <<< "${resp}")
        echo "api_token ${api_token}"
```

Currently I get the message that the service is not available (503). I have made numerous attempts in https://github.com/tschm/pyhrp. My suspicion is that I do something stupid with the POST request.

On pypi I have defined the trusted publisher for this particular project.

Comment: `'{"token":"${oidc_token}"}'` => `"{\"token\":\"${oidc_token}\"}"`

Comment: Shell variables won't expand in single quotes. Within double quotes, the nested JSON double quotes need to be escaped.

Comment: Ok, that changed the error message :-). It's now

Comment: RESP {"errors":[{"code":"invalid-payload","description":"1 validation error for TokenPayload\n__root__\n  Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 12 (char 11) (type=value_error.jsondecode; msg=Expecting ',' delimiter; doc={\"token\":\"\"***"\"}; pos=11; lineno=1; colno=12)"}],"message":"Token request failed"}
94
api_token null

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I put ${ocid_token} in double quotes although it comes already in double quotes. Once they are removed it starts to work. I will update the official documentation

Comment: Use raw output `-r` with `jq` instead i.e. `oidc_token=$(jq -r '.value' <<< "${resp}")`.

Comment: Better yet, let `jq` do everything i.e.  `json_data=$(jq -c '{"token": "\(.value)"} | @json' <<< "${resp}")`. No need to escape it manually. It's already escaped now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `'{"token":"${oidc_token}"}'`, the variable `oidc_token` won't expand as shell variables are not expanded if enclosed in single quotes.

So, using double quotes and escaping the nested double quotes should fix this.

Change

```
'{"token":"${oidc_token}"}'
```

to

```
"{\"token\":\"${oidc_token}\"}"
```

and, this should work.

Apart from that, here:

```bash
oidc_token=$(jq '.value' <<< "${resp}")
```

In the absence of raw output flag `-r`, there'll be double quotes surrounding the output i.e. `"token"`.

To fix this, use `-r`:

```bash
oidc_token=$(jq -r '.value' <<< "${resp}")
```

`oidc_token` won't have surrounding double quotes now i.e. `token`.

Better yet, you may let `jq` do everything for you i.e. creation of JSON with token and escaping too:

```bash
json_data=$(jq -c '{"token": "\(.value)"} | @json' <<< "${resp}")
```

`json_data` will now be:

```
"{\"token\":\"token\"}"
```

You may directly use it in your POST request with `-d` flag.